# Call to VirtualProtect sets the wrong protection

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application (Compiled with MSVC, Debug, x64) where I attempt to call VirtualProtect on a pointer to a function in order to change the page protection of the function code from PAGE_EXECUTE_READ to PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE.

I then query the region after VirtualProtect has been called. VirtualQuery returns that the page protection is now changed from PAGE_EXECUTE_READ to PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, which is not what I specified in the call to VirtualProtect. This is the code I am using:

```cpp
int foo(int n) { return n; }

int main() {
    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(foo, 16, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect)) {
        printf("VirtualProtect failed: 0x%lX\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    if (!VirtualQuery(foo, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) {
        printf("VirtualQuery failed: 0x%lX\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (mbi.Protect != PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE) {
        printf("Wrong protection set. Protection constant: 0x%lX\n", mbi.Protect);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and ran by me it produces the following output:

```
Wrong protection set. Protection constant: 0x80
```

I have made sure that foo does not point to a jmp instruction. I have also tried using VirtualProtectEx instead specifying a handle to the process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights, which produces the same result.

EDIT:
Compiling the same code in Release instead of Debug seems to make the issue go away, why is that?

Comment: What are you getting back in `dwOldProtect`?

Comment: @PaulSanders 0x20 (PAGE_EXECUTE_READ), which is the expected result.

Comment: It is just normal, presumably you are trying to patch a page mapped by a DLL.  When an address is shared by other processes then the OS cannot allow you to affect all of those other processes as well.  So it creates a new page, on demand, when you first write to the page.  That new page is PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE.  Just keep going, when VirtualProtect did not fail then you can assume you got what you asked for.  Eventually.

Comment: **after** you modify memory on this page, the protection changed from `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. until page not modified - it backed by image file. after modification - new page will be allocated, backed by page file and protection will be finally `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`

Comment: Basically [PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) verifies @RbMm 's answer. *`An attempt to write to a committed copy-on-write page results in a private copy of the page being made for the process. The private page is marked as PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, and the change is written to the new page.`*

Answer (score 2):

this is normal situation. i be say OS optimization. until page is not modified - it backed by image file itself. after you only change protection to writable - system continue use this page, but mark it as *copy on write*. but after first modification - system drop link between page and image file, and allocate new page, backed by page file, **copy** it content from old, and new page already will be have `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. so copy on write - this is exactly what system do.

i use such code for demo

```
void mm(PVOID lpAddress)
{
    ULONG dwOldProtect;
    if (VirtualProtect(lpAddress, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect))
    {
        DbgPrint("dwOldProtect = %x\n", dwOldProtect);

        ULONG n = 2;
        do 
        {
            MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
            if (VirtualQuery(lpAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
            {
                DbgPrint("%x / %x\n", mbi.Protect, mbi.AllocationProtect);
            }

            *(UCHAR*)lpAddress = *(UCHAR*)lpAddress;

        } while (--n);
    }
}
```

and have next output -

```
dwOldProtect = 20
80 / 80
40 / 80
```

if convert it to symbolic names:

```
dwOldProtect = PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY / PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE / PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
```